# Network Segregation by pfsense + ESXi VLAN

Tags: vlan, firewall, pfsense

**Given**

1. ESXi host with 1 NIC
2. Inside the host, there're 2 virtual switches: switch1 and switch2
3. In switch1, there's 1 WAN interface
4. In swtich2, there's 4 VLANs: VLAN10, VLAN20, VLAN30, and VLAN40

**Existing Situation:**

1. pfsense is used between switch1 and switch2 for routing
2. VM in each VLANs can access the Internet

**Purpose:**

1. prevent VM in VLAN40 access VM of other VLANs
2. allow VM access each other within VLAN40
3. allow VM in VLAN40 access the Internet

**What I have done to achieve the Purpose:**

1. I have created 3 firewall rules in VLAN40, which is illustrated as below image[image]
2. I have created an aliases, RFC1918, which includes:

   - 10.0.0.0/8
   - 172.16.0.0/12
   - 192.168.0.0/16

**Question:**

1. Are the firewall rules set correctly to achieve the purpose?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Purpose**:

1. prevent VM in VLAN40 access VM of other VLANs

Is done by rule 2, unless any of your VMs in the other VLANs gets a public IP address. If you are sure that won't happen, you're fine.

2. allow VM access each other within VLAN40

Access within the VLAN is switched and shouldn't even arrive at the firewall.

3. allow VM in VLAN40 access the Internet

pfsense will be the local DNS server, I assume from your first rule.

In short: Yes, should work, unless some pfsense- or ESXi-specific thing happens that I didn't think of. ;)

Comment: I found there're 3 ways to setup the DNS in pfsense. Any difference between them?
(1) System > General Setup > DNS servers
(2) Services > DNS Forwarder
(3) Services > DNS Resolver